# Why doesn't TS warn about impossible conditions with 'typeof' and 'in'?

Tags: typescript

In the 4.9 announcements, they have described [better narrowing with 'in'](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-9-beta/#unlisted-property-narrowing-with-the-in-operator) now. So, I took their example to the playground and tinkered with it. I found that impossible conditions with `typeof` and `in` were being narrowed to `never`, instead of generating a warning or error:

```
// Should be illegal but doesn't error out...?
if (typeof packageJSON.name === "string" && typeof packageJSON.name === "number") {
```

I thought that TypeScript would be able to deduce that `packageJSON.name` was a string, which means that checking if the type of `packageJSON.name` is a number on the right should be impossible. To my dismay, I also found that checking literals doesn't get TypeScript to gripe:

```
typeof 123 === "string" // OK, but is obviously impossible?
```

This behavior is also exhibited with `in`:

```
// How can it both have and not have the "name" key?
if (packageJSON && typeof packageJSON === "object" && "name" in packageJSON && !("name" in packageJSON)) {
```

To clarify, the types are *correctly narrowed* to `never`, but my expectations were that **TypeScript should be able to warn me about using an impossible condition**. TypeScript already does this for equality checks:

```
// TS knows that packageJSON is 0, so the RHS is impossible
if (packageJSON === 0 && packageJSON === 1) {
```

I don't know why this is happening. Is it by design or a limitation? What can I do to prevent or warn about this (maybe a linter)? Here's a [playground](https://tsplay.dev/mppDzm) with the examples above.

Comment: Related issue: [ms/TS#37804](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37804)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript is able to narrow types in cases where the type can be determined to be impossible based on the conditions. In the first example, since TypeScript knows that packageJSON.name is a string, it can deduce that the condition on the right is impossible and narrow the type to never. In the second example, TypeScript knows that the literal 123 is a number, so it can deduce that the condition on the right is impossible and narrow the type to never. In the third example, TypeScript knows that packageJSON is an object and that the "name" key exists on packageJSON, so it can deduce that the condition on the right is impossible and narrow the type to never.

This behavior is by design, as TypeScript is able to narrow down types in certain cases. However, if you want to prevent this behavior, you can use a linter like TSLint.

Comment: That's already amazing for a type system, and I understand this, but my question was why doesn't it generate an error like it does in my final example, where I erroneously check if `packageJSON` is equal to `0` *and* `1`?

Comment: This is not a limitation, but rather a feature that allows TypeScript to correctly narrow types in cases where the types can never be the same.There is no way to prevent or warn about this behavior, as it is not an error. However, if you are concerned about using impossible conditions, you can use a linter to check for them.

Comment: I think if you read more about the TS philosophy, you'll see that TS meant to be fully compatible with JS thus allows these to compile.

Comment: Well then my last example still stands... How come TypeScript correctly identifies an impossible condition when checking for `0` and `1`, but not `typeof` or `in`? We've just come back full circle. Also, which lint rule is it? I could not find anything about impossible/incorrect conditions.